# Layers created by GeoServer do not display in Mapbender3

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, mapbender

I have installed ***GeoServer 2.7.2*** on my local windows 7 machine, which retrieves data from a remote ***PostgreSQL*** server. The data is represented in layers just fine!

I also have installed ***Mapbender3*** locally and I have introduced the local GeoServer as the ***layer source***. The problem is that the layers are not displayed in Mapbender application while their names are listed there in Mapbender's layer tree. I have set the map's SRS to `ESPG:3395` as it is declared originally in GeoServer.
[image]

Please help me with why the layers are not loaded in the Mapbender application!

Comment: can you show us the mapbender code? do the layers appear in the GeoServer preview?

Comment: Yes, the layers are displayed in GeoServer preview!